# disabling (unloading) a launchd job only after it finishes

Tags: launchd, plist

I have some job that runs in the background I loaded with:

```
launchctl load -w com.xxx.jobname
```

Whenever I want to disable the job I run:

```
launchctl unload -w com.xxx.jobname
```

I noticed that  `launchctl unload -w` stops the job immediately, and I'm trying to avoid this from happening.

When the job is running the script, I see the process has a PID in:

```
launchctl list | grep com.xxx.jobname
```

And when the script is not running, PID is blank.

I'm thinking of simply sleeping for 10 seconds and then trying to unload again, but there has got to be a better way I hope.

The plist file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.xxx.jobname</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>

        <key>TERM</key>
        <string>xterm</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>XXscript-pathXX</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>40</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: IMHO the whole logic underneath your script/launchagent is flawed. A background job which has to be (override-)loaded and (override-)unloaded manually isn't really a background job. A job ran at load and then every 40 seconds again, isn't really a background job and shouldn't be (override-)loaded and (override-)unloaded manually. You should add some conditional statement at the beginning of the script which determines whether the rest of the script has to be executed at all in the light of the circumstances at the time.